# How to list every redirect for a single URL using PHP

Tags: php, http-headers

I'm trying to build a little web application on WordPress that will take a URL and list all redirects that it generates, but I'm running into issues where some sites state to use curl, some wp_remote_head, some get_header, and others file_get_contents but none are working well at all. I'm also seeing that some headers may pass "location" and others "Location".

Additional: Because it's using WordPress, I'm calling this function via Ajax and then setting the results in a transient so that if someone bombards the page, it doesn't kill my site. I have another function that looks for "error" and updates a status div. The resulting unordered list is displayed in a results div.

Problem: It's not listing the redirects, it always shows that no redirect was found.

Ultimately, I'd like `traceredirects` to respond with:

- Origin: http://marketingtechblog.com
- Redirect (301): http://martech.zone
- Redirect (301): https://martech.zone
- Destination (200): https://martech.zone

```php
function traceredirects() {
    check_ajax_referer( 'traceredirects_nonce', 'nonce' );
    $url = $_POST['url'];

    $valid_url = filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
    if (!$valid_url) {
        echo '<strong>Error:</strong> Please enter a valid URL with http:// or https://';
        wp_die();
    }

    $host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
    if(!checkdnsrr($host, 'ANY')) {
        echo '<strong>Error:</strong> Could not find the domain ' . $host;
        wp_die();
    }

    $transient_name = $url . '_traceredirect';
    $traced = get_transient( $transient_name );

    if (false === $traced) {
        $args = array(
            'redirection' => 10, // follow up to 10 redirects
        );

        $redirects = array();
        $redirects[] = $url;
        $response = wp_remote_get( $url, $args );

        $headers = wp_remote_retrieve_headers( $response );
        $http_code = wp_remote_retrieve_response_code( $response );

        $traced = '<ul>';

        if ( ! is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
            if (!isset($headers['location'])) {
                $traced .= '<li>No redirects found</li>';
            } else {
                while (isset($headers['location'])) {
                    if ( in_array( $headers['location'], $redirects ) ) {
                        echo 'Error: Redirect loop detected';
                        break;
                    }
                    $redirects[] = $headers['location'];
                    $response = wp_remote_get( $headers['location'], $args );
                    $headers = wp_remote_retrieve_headers( $response );
                    $http_code = wp_remote_retrieve_response_code( $response );
                    $traced .= '<li>HTTP code: ' . $http_code . ', URL: ' . $headers['location'] . '</li>';
                }
            }   
        } else {
            echo 'Error: ' . $response->get_error_message();
            wp_die();
        }

        $traced .= '</ul>';
        set_transient( $transient_name, $traced, HOUR_IN_SECONDS );
    }
    echo $traced;
    wp_die();
    }
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_traceredirects', 'traceredirects' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_traceredirects', 'traceredirects' );
```

Comment: If I were debugging this, my first act would be to use a `var_dump()` and a `die` to show the value of the `$headers` variable right after this line: `$headers = wp_remote_retrieve_headers( $response );`. Then you'll at least know whether you're receiving headers at all. Then you could move on to the next step. One step at a time.

Comment: I would break this into smaller tasks, at least two, maybe more. The first task is just getting the location, if set and following it and repeating. I'd 100% skip all AJAX and transient stuff for now. Personally I'd build this so that I could interact with it using WP CLI, too, which makes debugging so much easier, IMHO. I'd also only accept redirects for 301, 302, 307 and 308 status codes. Once you get a good algorithm, I'd then maybe break it up into some form of queue system where you drop off a URL and receive a token, work happens, and you later present the token to "pickup" the results.

Comment: All of the functions you listed ultimately do the same thing. Curl is **very** powerful but also sometimes too powerful. `file_get_content` is very simple but you can override things with a stream context (which is ugly IMHO). And the WP stuff is pluggable which may or may not be a good thing. I'd actually probably use something like Guzzle or Symfony's HTTP client because I prefer to work in a more OOP way these days, and those tools work completely fine in a WP environment, but it is just a personal preference